# Will OpenLaszlo mouse events convert to touch events if i compile the code for mobile target?

Tags: touch, mouseevent, openlaszlo, lzx

I want to know whether the open laszlo mouse down events will be converted to touch events while compiling it in mobile format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least on iPad. I tested this myself on an iPad2 running the OpenLaszlo 4.9.0 in HTML5 (aka DHTML) mode of my application last year for R&D purposes and the following were confirmed to work:

1) Touching a button on the screen in the application in OpenLaszlo HTML5 mode properly triggered the onclick event of the button.

2) Drag and drop with your finger on a touch screen in OpenLaszlo HTML5 mode has the same result as dragging and dropping with the mouse on a non-touch screen system.

Note: This was only tested on the iPad2, it was not tested on Android, Windows Phone, Blackberry, etc.

Comment: Here is the [corresponding JIRA issue](http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-8904), I remember that the team worked on the touch events last year, and got it working in iPad.  The test file which is used to verify the functionality can be found in SVN here: http://svn.openlaszlo.org/openlaszlo/trunk/examples/touchevents.lzx

Answer (score 2):

Flash is not relevant for mobile (since Flash Player has just been removed from Google Play store), but Adobe AIR for Android and iOS is an option, if you want to build native applications. In that case, you have to start capturing the touch events using the ActionScript3 API.

Comment: Adobe air i don't understand this AIR is present in IOS that means can i wrap the DHTML open laszlo app and still use actionscript3 api? Is there any POC's or code examples i am not getting anything in internet for this?

Comment: The Adobe AIR SDK supports compiling an application into a native iOS, Android or Blackberry Playbook OS: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices.html I've created a video showing how an OpenLaszlo app can automatically be compiled into an Android AIR app using the OpenLaszlo server, the Adobe AIR SDK, and a simple Ant build script: http://vimeo.com/14014507

Comment: Another video, showing a simple multi-touch OpenLaszlo app running on a Nexus One: http://vimeo.com/14972608 The LZX is compiled into ActionScript 3, and then the Air SDK is used to package the application into an Android APK file. With more modern versions of the Air SDK you can build a native app without using the AIR runtime.